# ggplot yaxis with arrow

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

Is there anyone who knows how to change the y-axis horizontally and add the arrow?
I want to make graph like this.
This is the code that I used for making this graph.

```
ggplot(plot, aes(x=Worried.about.the.problems.caused.by.the.garbage., y=mean))
+ geom_bar(stat = "identity", position ="dodge", fill='#6699FF') + theme_minimal()+ ggtitle("Korea") + theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "serif", face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 15, color = "black"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add colored arrow to axis of ggplot2 (partially outside plot region)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140058/add-colored-arrow-to-axis-of-ggplot2-partially-outside-plot-region)

Comment: This looks like you could use annotations (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html)

Comment: Please consider accepting the given answer, so that this question is not flagged as unanswered anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can adjust the elements in the plot using `theme` to add an arrow to the y-axis instead of using an `annotate` layer.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), 
                                                       ends = "both")))
```

As for the axis labels for "dumping more" and "dumping less", using `annotate` is probably easiest, but if you really wanted to avoid it for some reason, you could use line breaks in your y-axis title and adjust the angle of the title in `theme`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), 
                                                       ends = "both")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0)) +
  labs(y = "More Common\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nLess Common")
```

With the output:
[image]

Comment: Shame the question was closed, this answer is better than the linked answer