# How to change axis lines to arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2

**edit**

How can I change axis lines to arrows on my plot?

Here a sample plot where both axis should have arrows at the end (plot from user [chemdork123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62638434/7941188)).

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_point() + theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!  Please, be sure to include your dataset when you also include code in order for everyone to replicate your question.  Sharing a smaller-sized dataset can be done via pasting the output of `dput(your.data.frame)` into your question as code.  Alternatively, you can always pose your question using one of the built-in datasets of R, such as `mtcars`, `iris`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

To represent the x or y axis as an arrow, you can access the `theme()` elements for those objects. [This is a good place to go for information on the theme objects you can modify](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html).

In this case, you'll want to access `axis.line` (for all axes) or `axis.line.x` or `axis.line.y` to access either x or y axes individually.  The arguments must be changed via calling `element_line()` and then within `element_line()` there is an argument for `arrow=` where you can use the `arrow()` function to change the look of the arrows.

Here's an example using `mtcars`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_point() + theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(arrow = arrow(type='closed', length = unit(10,'pt'))))
```

[image]